# Efficient work with numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am  having some troubles with Python.
I'm solving some programming tasks with Python(topcoder, codeforces). And sometimes i need to count something. For example: count substrings in string or something else. And when i counting as follows:

```
counter += 1
```

My solution fails on some test. I investigated this and found that my code should count to something near 200000. I know numbers in python is objects. And my code trying to create this 200000 objects and therefore test time limit is exceed. In one task i was able to optimize algorithm and it finally required totally lower addition. But in another one it's impossible and my code failed because it should create many numbers objects.
My primary language is C#, so i'm wondering, how  should i work with Python numbers in efficient way?

I cann't find any similar problem there and so I'm asking question.

Comment: What was the task your code failed in?

Comment: I propose that it is not the fact that you are coding in Python that means you are timing out, but your algorithm being a complexity level too inefficient meaning you are timing out (for instance the problem expects an O(nlogn) complexity solution and sets the timeout such that no O(n^2) can make it even in C++ while any O(nlogn) even in Python can make it).

Comment: I should count substrings in string.

Comment: Do you think that if i increment some variable to 200000 it's 'easy' in python? Does it create 200000 objects? And yes, i'l check my algorithm complexity todays evening.

Comment: If you need to count to 200000 then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you provide us with the question link ? The counter+=1 is atomic and takes constant time and does not change the complexity of the algorithm . The questions in topcoder/codeforces are more of algorithm intensive than language intensive. Probably you need to come up with a better algorithm .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ python -m timeit 'counter = 0
> for _ in xrange(200000): counter += 1'
100 loops, best of 3: 9.25 msec per loop
```

Do less than 10 msec make such a big difference for your tests? I don't think so.

Most probably the `counter += 1` instruction is *not* the bottleneck. You probably have the wrong algorithm or you are implementing the algorithm in the wrong way.

---

Using a `while`:

```
$ python -m timeit 'counter = 0
> while counter < 200000: counter += 1'
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 msec per loop
```

Comment: Using a generator function (`xrange`) is a bad way to showcase this timing. You should use a naked while loop testing (counter < 20000). generators create stack frame overhead at the very least.

Comment: @PreetKukreti So what? If they have overhead than this should mean that the `9.25 msec` is a loose "overtiming" which makes even more my point: The problem is not the counter nor the loop. By the way: in python `while` loops are slower than `for` loops(see updated answer).

Comment: @Bariku good point, it actually emphasises your argument. Also I see my suggestion is actually slower than xrange. So it seems I was wrong. Another lesson in profile first, worry later :). +1

Comment: Although having said the above, I'm familiar with some of these programming challenge/test suites, and some of them DO in fact have 10ms-level granularity on their complexity checks (e.g. [codility](http://codility.com/)). I think they test these as an average over multiple runs. It could be the tipping point, but I doubt it would be without the absence of some algorithmic blunder.